# How to show that the vector fields $X_i = f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ and $X_j = f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$ commute?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Could anyone help me with the following problem?
We have:

> Fix $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$ and choose a smooth function $h$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $h'(t) > 0$ for all $t ≥ 0$, $h(t) = t$ for $t \in [0, \varepsilon]$, $h(t) = 1 − \frac{1}{\ln t}$ for all $t$ large enough.
>
> Consider the map $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(a) = \frac{h(\lVert a \rVert)}{\lVert a \rVert} a$, where $\lVert a \rVert = \sqrt{ (a^1)^2 + \cdots + (a^n)^2}$ is the usual Euclidean norm. We have that $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto the open unit ball $B$.
>
> Define smooth vector fields $X_i$  on $B$  by $X_i = f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$, that is, $$X_i(b) = (d_{f^{-1}(b)}f)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \lvert _{f^{-1}(b)}).$$ Put $X_i(p) = 0$ for $p \notin B$. Then the vector fields $X_i$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are smooth and $X_i(p) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \lvert_{p}$ for $\lVert p \rVert \leq \varepsilon.$

**The problem**

> Explain why the vector fields $X_i$ and $X_j$ pairwise commute.

**What I have so far**

I'm using Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry I*, and the definition of $f_∗$ (for a differentiable map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$) is defined as the union of the maps $f_{∗p}:\mathbb{R}^n_{\ \ p} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m_{\ \ f(p)}$ defined as $f_{∗p}(v_p) = [Df(p)(v)]_{f(p)}$.

So, my thoughts are that $X_i = f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = Df(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$, so I fix a coordinate system $(y,U)$ and then my $Df$ is equal to the Jacobi matrix of $f$: $[\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial y^t}]_{s,t = 1,\dots, n}$.

Then I want to find out what $Df(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ is. Do we just get that 
$$Df(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \\
\end{bmatrix}?
$$
I know that I want to find out what $X_j(X_i(g))$ is, and show that that is equal to $X_i(X_j(g))$.

Any help is much appreciated! Anyone?

Comment: Although you can just compute it out, are you acquainted with the result that $[f_*X, f_*Y]=f_*[X,Y]$ for general vector fields $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @Ted: No, I'm not familiar with that result, unfortunately. I would like to just compute it, if I could. But the $f_*$-part of the vector field throws me a little. I don't know how to show that $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}) = f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Well, sure, if you insist, write $f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) = \sum b^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$, and write out the action of the two sides of your equality on an arbitrary function $g$ on the range space.

Comment: @Ted: I updated the question with an edit (it was too long as a comment), does it look correct? Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: First of all, you are forgetting the product rule: the $c^t$ are functions. Indeed, you need to use the particular form of the vector field, i.e., that $f$ is involved. So you need to express the $b^s$ and $c^t$ in terms of derivatives of components of $f$ (in the local coordinates $x^i$ and $y^s$).

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now that if what I did was correct, we would have that _any_ two vector fields would commute.

Comment: @Ted: I'm using Spivak's _A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry I_, and the definition of $f_*$ (for a differentiable map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$) is defined as the union of the maps $f_{*p}: \mathbb{R}^n _{\ \ \ p} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m _{\ \ \ f(p)}$ defined as $f_{*p}(v_p) = [Df(p)(v)]_{f(p)}$.

A silly question: the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ in $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ is just the $n$-tuple $[0 \ \ \dots \ \ 0 \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \ \ 0 \ \ \dots \ \ 0]$, right?

Comment: The $n$-tuple $(a^1,\dots,a^n)$ corresponds to the tangent vector $\sum a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: Right. ... so do we get $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \sum_s \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$?

Comment: @Ted: If it is, then I'm getting that $f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})(g) = \sum_{s,t} (\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial y^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}))(g)$, am I on the right track here?